# Why do I need to point a variable to a structure

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors

In the 2 code samples below (the first codeblock below works and the 2nd lower code block doesn't)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct padStruct
{
    int buttonID;
    long timeMS;
    std::string codetoSEND;
};

int main()
{
    padStruct s = {0,0,""}, *s2;
    s2 = &s;
    s.buttonID = 3; //or (*s2).buttonID = 3;
    s.timeMS = 1200; //or (*s2).timeMS = 1200;
    s.codetoSEND = "play song"; //or (*s2).codetoSEND = "play song";
    std::cout << (*s2).buttonID << ',' << (*s2).timeMS << ',' << '"' << (*s2).codetoSEND << '"' << '\n';
}
```

This works.

As opposed to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct padStruct
{
    int buttonID;
    long timeMS;
    std::string codetoSEND;
};

int main()
{
    padStruct *s = {0};
    //padStruct *s = {0,0,""} //Error C2078 too many initializers
    (*s).buttonID = 3; //or (*s2).buttonID = 3;
    (*s).timeMS = 1200; //or (*s2).timeMS = 1200;
    (*s).codetoSEND = "play song"; //or (*s2).codetoSEND = "play song";
    std::cout << (*s).buttonID << ',' << (*s).timeMS << ',' << '"' << (*s).codetoSEND << '"' << '\n';
}
```

This doesn't.

Can someone simply explain

1. Why I can't initialize padStruct *s = {0,0,"") on the bottom code while it works on the top otherwise I get an ***Error C2078 too many initializers***|
2. More importantly why I have to create a padStruct variable s and then a padStruct *s2 and have to then point the s2 to s? Otherwise I get a ***error C2228: left of '.buttonID' must have class/struct/union***.

Very confusing. Maybe explain at least the 2nd question a bit easy so it sinks in. Thanks.

Comment: The short answer is "because C++ doesn't work this way". Reread the chapter in your C++ that discusses what pointers are, and how they work.

Comment: Um.. Because in the top version you have a class object, while in the bottom code you have a *pointer* to a class object. These are two completely different things with completely different semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why I can't initialize `padStruct *s = {0, 0, "")`

Because `s` is a pointer, not a composite type. It can be initialized to zero the way you did, or to a pointer to new instance of `padStruct`, but it's a single item.

> why I have to create a `padStruct` variable `s` and then a `padStruct *s2` and have to then point `s2` to `s`?

You need to initialize `s2` pointer to point to an instance of `padStruct`. Pointing it to `s` is one option, but there are other options. For example, you can write

```
padStruct *s = new padStruct { 0, 0, "" };
```

or even

```
padStruct *s = new padStruct { 3, 1200, "play song" };
```

to avoid setting fields one by one.

Note that you can use `s->buttonID` syntax in place of `(*s).buttonID`.

Comment: That was simple. Thanks very much for that clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

At the first block , you define a actual `padStruct s` object and define another simply **pointer** `s2` to `padStruct`.

```
padStruct s = {0,0,""}, *s2
```

For `s2 = &s`, making `s2` to pointer to `s` is nothing wrong, the `s2` pointer the address of `s`, which is allocated at stack. So when you dereference `s2` by `(*s2).buttonID`, the value actually come from `s`. (Same as `s.buttonID`)

At next block, what you are doing is `initialize a pointer with {0}`. This is wrong. Pointer should be initialized as `0` or `nullptr`. And the `{0}` only works for `POD struct`.

```
padStruct *s = {0};
```

You need prepare the space for `s` like `padStruct *s = new padStruct`, then the `s` will actually pointer to something real. And remember to delete it in the end.

Comment: Thanks, basblinkenlight explained it a little and you gave a little more in depth. I appreciate it. :)